# Retrieve individual documents from tree structure - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, tree, nested

In MongoDB, I have documents (comments) that looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": { "$oid": "61acd4474bbaa88d12c38199" },
   "textContent": "This comment has 2 replies",
   "replies": [
     { "$oid": "61acd57fe06fed9e70462139" },
     { "$oid": "61acd57fe06fed9e7046213a" },
   ],
   "__v": 0
},
{
   "_id": { "$oid": "61acd57fe06fed9e70462139" },
   "textContent": "This comment has 0 replies",
   "replies": [],
   "__v": 0
},
{
   "_id": { "$oid": "61acd57fe06fed9e7046213a" },
   "textContent": "This comment has 0 replies",
   "replies": [],
   "__v": 0
}
```

All comments are stored in the same type of object, with an array, "replies", that contains IDs of other comments. It's like a nested tree structure, but the documents are stored separately in MongoDB.

When documents are sent from the server, I would like them to remain separate documents and only contain ID references to other comments -- not the comments themselves. In other words, the objects should look like they do on the server.

How do you request all of the comments above in a single query, but keep the comments as separate documents? Please note that the level of nesting could be deeper than in the above example. Also, we don't know the ID of the top comment beforehand.

I know that populate can be helpful when you want to query nested documents. My issue with populate is that you receive a large nested object instead of the individual documents.

```
this.populate({ path: 'replies' })
```

Output:

```
{ _id: "61acd4474bbaa88d12c38199",
  textContent: "This comment has 2 replies",
  replies: [
    { _id: "61acd57fe06fed9e70462139",
      textContent: "This comment has 0 replies",
      replies: []
    },
    { _id: "61acd57fe06fed9e7046213a",
      textContent: "This comment has 0 replies",
      replies: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
[
   { _id: "61acd4474bbaa88d12c38199",
     textContent: "This comment has 2 replies",
     replies: [ "61acd57fe06fed9e70462139", "61acd57fe06fed9e7046213a" ]
   },
   { _id: "61acd57fe06fed9e70462139",
     textContent: "This comment has 0 replies",
     replies: [ ]
   },
   { _id: "61acd57fe06fed9e7046213a",
     textContent: "This comment has 0 replies",
     replies: [ ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline to get the desired output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "61acd4474bbaa88d12c38199"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "replies",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "repliesPopulated"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "repliesPopulated": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$$ROOT.repliesPopulated",
          [
            {}
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$repliesPopulated"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              "$repliesPopulated",
              {}
            ]
          },
          "then": "$repliesPopulated",
          "else": "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "repliesPopulated"
  }
])
```

In this pipeline, we first match the required document. Then we populate the replies in the `repliesPopulated` key. We then add an empty object in this array and unwind it. Finally, using `$replaceRoot` we bring the populated comments to the top level.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hmT7o3ly-nf)

Comment: Thank you! I notice that the top comment, 61acd4474bbaa88d12c38199, is hard coded. What if we don't know the ID of the top comment? If the comment is fetched by some other principle, like age or popularity, then I wouldn't know the ID beforehand. Sorry, I should have made this clear in the question.

Comment: Then we can modify the `$match` stage accordingly. @candleout

Comment: `$match` is just for filtering. If you want to check for all docs. Check this playground. https://mongoplayground.net/p/HyXp_eNsjz3

Comment: There seems to be an issue with your query, because you get back duplicates of two comments. Trying to solve it with $reduce...

Comment: The duplicates will be there because of $lookup. You can use $group to remove duplicates. https://mongoplayground.net/p/8nwwWyhGB3F

Comment: @candleout check the link above

Comment: Thank you CK, this worked like a charm! One more thing I take away from this is that I need to learn more about the aggregation pipeline :-) But I've already managed to tweak the code a bit to better suite my needs.